# Can I use identityHashCode to produce a compareTo between Objects respecting same-ness?

Tags: java, comparator, java.util.concurrent, skip-lists, concurrentskiplistmap

I want to implement a simple comparator between two Objects, whose only requirements are that

1. it is a valid comparator (i.e. defines a linear order on all objects) and
2. `.compare` will return 0 if and only if the objects are *the same*.

Will `Comparator.comparing(System::identityHashCode)` work? Is there another way?

**Motivation:**
I want to build a collection that will allow me to store time-stamped messages in a thread-safe collection, which will support queries like "get me all the messages whose timestamp lies in [a,b)".

It seems that Guava's `TreeMultimap` uses a global lock (edit: if wrapped with the `synchronizedSortedSetMultimap` wrapper), and `ConcurrentSkipListMap` seems to support only one entry per time (it is a map, not a multi map). So I thought of using just a set of pairs:

`ConcurrentSkipListSet<ImmutablePair<Float,Message>> db`,

where the pairs are lexically ordered, first by the times (using `Float.compareTo`) and then by something like `Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(System::identityHashCode))`.

- The `nullsFirst` is there just so `db.subSet(ImmutablePair.of(a,null), ImmutablePair.of(b,null))` queries the half-open time interval [a,b).
- You see why I care about the comparator preserving sameness: if the message comparator returns zero for non-same messages, messages may be deleted.
- You also see why I don't need much else from the comparator: it's just there so I can use the storage mechanism of `ConcurrentSkipListSet`. I certainly don't want to impose on the user (well, just me :-) to implement a comparator for `Message`.
- Another possible solution is to use a `ConcurrentSkipListMap<Float, Set<Message>>` (with thread-safe  Set<> instances) but it seems a bit wasteful in terms of memory, and I will need to remove emptySet's myself to save memory once messages are deleted.

**EDIT:** As several people noted, identityHashCode may produce collisions, and in fact I've now confirmed that such collisions exist in my setup (which is roughly equivalent to having 4K collections as above, each populated with 4K messages per time bin). This is most likely the reason I see some messages dropped. So I'm now even more interested than ever in finding some way to have an "agnostic" comparison operator, that *truly* respects sameness. Actually, a 64 bit hash value (instead of the 32bit value provided by identityHashCode) would probably suffice.

Comment: Note: the contract of `compareTo` requires that it is consistent with equality. You can violate this contract if you are sure you know what you are doing; but it might have surprising effects.

Comment: `System::identityHashCode` doesn't guarantee that non equal objects will have distinct hash codes. Hence your `.compare will return 0 if and only if the objects are the same.` requirement is not guaranteed to be satisfied.

Comment: @AndyTurner: No, the contract *doesn't* require it to be consistent with equality. The documentation explicitly states that it *doesn't* have to be - but that when it's not consistent with equality, you may get odd results in some situations.

Comment: I may be missing something but wouldn't using `equals` be more straight forward approach here? Comparisons are mostly for ordering objects, not for detecting equal objects.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul the mechanism of (Concurrent)SkipListSet relies on being able to compare any two elements in the collection.

Comment: Try Guava’s `Ordering.arbitrary()` which will induce a total ordering among all unique objects.

Comment: @StuartMarks looks like this does the job, thanks! (I've switched to a map to sets for now, but I might come back to this set of pairs solution to see if it is faster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @StuartMarks noted in his comment, Guava supports
`Ordering.arbitrary()`, which provides thread-safe collision handling. The implementation makes an efficient use of `identityHashCode`:

```
@Override
public int compare(Object left, Object right) {
  if (left == right) {
    return 0;
  } else if (left == null) {
    return -1;
  } else if (right == null) {
    return 1;
  }
  int leftCode = identityHashCode(left);
  int rightCode = identityHashCode(right);
  if (leftCode != rightCode) {
    return leftCode < rightCode ? -1 : 1;
  }

  // identityHashCode collision (rare, but not as rare as you'd think)
  int result = getUid(left).compareTo(getUid(right));
  if (result == 0) {
    throw new AssertionError(); // extremely, extremely unlikely.
  }
  return result;
}
```

so only if there is a hash collision, `getUid` (which uses a memoized AtomicInteger counter to allocate uid's) is invoked.

It's also quite easy to write (perhaps less easy to read?) the desired timestamped message container in "one" line:

```
db = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(
                (Ordering.<Float>natural().<ImmutablePair<Float,Message>>onResultOf(x -> x.left))
                        .compound(Ordering.arbitrary().nullsFirst().<ImmutablePair<Float,Message>>onResultOf(x -> x.right)))
```

Answer (score 3):

While it's not *guaranteed*, I suspect the chances of this causing a problem are vanishingly small.

`System.identityHashCode` returns the value that `Object.hashCode` would return if not overridden, including this [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()):

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects.

So is "as much as is reasonably practical" sufficient? While it's not guaranteed, I would be very surprised if you ever ran into a situation where it causes a problem. You'd have to have two messages with exactly the same timestamp *and* where the JVM's `Object.hashCode` implementation returns the same value for the two messages.

If the result of that coincidence were to be "nuclear power plant explodes" then I wouldn't risk it. If the result of that coincidence were to be "we fail to bill a customer" - or even "we bill a customer twice, and might get sued" I'd probably accept that chance, if no better alternatives are suggested.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I thought too, you'd need something like 4G messages in a time bin to get a collision, and that's even without the implementation trying to anti-correlate the hash values. But is there a reason why the guarantee is only partial? Is it too difficult to provide a full guarantee in a parallel context?

Comment: correction: I see identityHashCode returns a 32 bit int - so you only need a little over 64K messages in a time bin to get an expected collision, assuming random values.

Comment: @JustMe: Not sure what you mean by an "expected" collision, but I think the chances of a collision with 64K messages is still pretty small - and of course they're *not* random values, in that the implementation is *trying* to return unique values.

Comment: @JustMe: Having tested this myself just now, I was wrong... admittedly using a 31-bit range rather than a 32-bit range, but with 64K samples, a random selection fails about 63% of the time. With 10,000 samples (and a 31-bit range) it fails 2.5% of the time.  But I still think that with the additional "JVM is trying to make them unique" you'll be okay.

Comment: I meant "the expected value of the random variable counting the collisions is at least one" (when this happens, the probability of getting a collision becomes significant, and grows quickly with the number of messages until it is close to 1; all of this happens at around the square root of the number of possible values, assuming randomness). I agree that randomness is a pessimistic approximation, but without a strong guarantee, it's hard to know just how pessimistic...

Comment: looks like our messages almost collided in time! :-)

Comment: @JustMe: Agreed that it's hard to be sure. Do you have stats about how many values you're likely to get with the same timestamp? (And any reason the timestamp is a `float`? That's an unusual way of timestamping.) Ultimately you'll probably want to test it hard on the JVM implementation you're planning on using.

Comment: These messages are passed around as part of a parallel computation. On a simplified problem, I have 4K instances of the above collection, each with 4K messages in each time bin. I do see some messages dropped - but since I'm quite adept at producing all kinds of bugs, it's still hard to conclude that hash collisions are the reason. I can say the same message is dropped consistently, when running in a single thread.

Comment: The choice of float is tied to the problem I'm trying to solve (I need a "sticky" infinity, and since I'm storing many numbers I want to save memory by using float instead of double)

Comment: @JustMe - One idea would be to have your comparator do a second test to confirm equality upon an initial positive result, thereby getting the best of both worlds...quick comparisons most of the time, but no chance of a false equality.  A lot of variables go into if this is a good idea or not, most notably the cost of doing the additional check combined with the frequency of positive matches.  I's just an idea I thought might be helpful in considering.

Answer (score 0):

> Will Comparator.comparing(System::identityHashCode) work? Is there another way?

As mentioned, identityHashCode is not unique.

> Actually, a 64 bit hash value (instead of the 32bit value provided by identityHashCode) would probably suffice

I think this would just be reducing the chances of overlap, not removing them.  Hash algorithems are designed to *limit* overlaps but typically have no guarantees about none.  For example, MD5 is 128 bit and still has overlaps.

How about just assigning a unique number to each message with `AtomicLong`.  Then your comparison function would do:

1. Compare by time.  I would use long if possible instead of float.
2. If same time then compare by the unique value.

If you have multiple systems doing the ingesting of these messages then you are going to need to record unique system-id and message number to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks! I think the Ordering.arbitrary() solution is similar to what you're suggesting, except messages are first compared using their identityHashCode and, only if that produces a hit, they get a assigned a unique id: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65405632/9398584
This should reduce contention on the global uid provider.